# Static variable in a function called repeatedly C

Tags: c, static, initialization

I am writing a function which is meant to be called multiple times, where I want to have a static pointer to the beginning of a list. I need the function, no matter how many times it is called, to access the same list, so I have two questions.

1. Am I right that if I declare it `static t_line *begin = NULL;` where `t_line` is my struct, I believe it will already have allocated the correct space before `main()` is called, as I understand `static` variables do, then this will give me a null pointer with the correct allocated size.
2. Once I give that static pointer the address of the first element in my list, the next time the function is called and it reaches that declaration line, wouldn't it just reset it to `NULL` and I'd lose my pointer?

Comment: It gives you a null pointer and that's it. There's no allocation anywhere, except the static variable itself, which is allocated in the bss segment.

Comment: "[...] a null pointer with the correct allocated size" makes no sense at all. You get a pointer, that's the variable itself (`begin`), but there will be no further "allocation". A pointer to a given type always has the same size, there's nothing that can't be "correct" there.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was thinking about it totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables with `static` storage are initialized only once, you're good to go.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.4, *emphasis mine*

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and **its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.**

That said, regarding retaining the last-stored value, quoting paragraph 2, (*again, my emphasis*)

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
>   guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,<sup>33)</sup> and **retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.**<sup>34)</sup> [....]

and, for `static` variables, as mentioned above

> Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program

Comment: The _"prior to program startup"_ is important (it also implies the initializer can only be compile-time constant(s)). The initialization statement is not performed upon the (first) call of the function, but (as said), at program startup.